# UIKIt making the same view model instance available for all tabs

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I want to use the same view model across different tabs of my tabbed UIKit application. In SwiftUI, I could create a `@StateObject var` on the root and pass it as an `.environmentObject` to the `ContentView` containing the `TabView` which would make it available for the tab items. What would be the best way to achieve this having a UIKIt application with a UITabBarController ?

My thoughts: pass the view model reference to each of the view controllers ? Or use delegates / Combine ?

Comment: There is no "built-in" way in UIKit but there are many design patterns that accomplish this. Discussing which would be "best" for your project is opinion based and out of scope for SO. Do research on design patterns. There are many options.

Comment: @loremipsum I have a basic understanding of Singleton, MVC, MVVM, Adapter, Observer Pattern etc. but I am not sure what should I exactly search for regarding design patterns. Could give a hint ?